# Detect 180 flip on iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I am doing some rejigging of various views from portrait to landscape in my iPhone app. This works fine if the user does Portrait -> Landscape -> Portrait -> Landscape (as I do some math do relocate the views).

However if a user goes from Portait -> Portrait upside down, or Landscape Left -> Landscape Right, my code doesn't work.

Can I detect the 180 flip and ignore it? I tried the following:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) && 
        (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
    } 
    else if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
             (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) && 
             (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)))
    {
    } 
    else 
    {
      // Do something - it didn't flip 180.
    }
}
```

Comment: While you could ignore it (see @Jim Buck), the better approach would be to fix the bug that prevents your code to work correctly. Probably just a minor thing.

Comment: Well my math works based on the previous position, so if the previous position hasn't moved then I don't want to do the math... My ignore code above doesn't work though, even with Jim's code...

Comment: In the landscape check, you're checking to see if from is LandscapeRight or Left. In the portrait, you're not checking to see if the from is Portrait upsidedown. And maybe update your code so the others can see that your parens are correctly updated based on what @Jim Buck has pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have parentheses around this part of your logic:

```
fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

.. otherwise your logic won't come out as your are expecting. `&&` has higher precedence over `||`.

Comment: Thanks - done that but the code still calls the final else on a 180 degree flip...?

Comment: Well, which condition is causing? Is the 'from' orientation incorrect, or is the 'to' orientation incorrect?